# The cardinality of infinite binary word

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cardinals, infinite-groups

I know that the cardinality of all binary words is $2^{\aleph_0}$,
but in my assignment I need to find out what is the cardinality of all finite and infinite binary words excluding those that contain the sequence $01$.

I think there are just 3 options:

$(1,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ finite sequence of $1$'s and then infinite sequence of $0$'s

$(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$

$(1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)$

Since the first option is countable the answer should be $|R^N| =$ $2^{\aleph_0}$
Am I right?

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi why are you putting just $\aleph$, without any subindex. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wore I agree with your interpretation, but I believe that you should comment, rather than edit in this case, because editing should not change  the question in substantial ways.

Comment: For both I mean $2^ℵ0$ , same as |R|

Comment: @OfirNir But you just argued that the infinite binary words with no occurrence of $01$ are countable...

Comment: Use curly braces instead of round parentheses to enclose your superscripts.

Answer (score 5):

$\aleph$ is not a cardinal. It is $\aleph_0$.Next, youare right for your three cases. But then, it means that the cardinality you seek is $\aleph_0$ (and not $2^{\aleph_0}$). Indeed, you have an surjection from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N $ to the set of finite and infinite binary words excluding those that contain the sequence 01. Namely, to $(m,n)$ we assign the sequence with $m$ ones and $n-2$ zeros if $n \ge 2$, $m$ ones and infinitely many $0$ if $n=1$ and infinitely many $m$ otherwise.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Actually it is an answer since the OP asked if his solution was right, not for a solution.